# How to not let Google Sites resize image based on above / below text?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites, google-sites-2016

Basically, I want to add an image above a text block, but it is way too huge ( the same size as the text ). [image: Imense logo]

I want something like this.

[image]

I imagine there is no possible way to do it with google sites, but rather by script. Even so, is it possible, or is the google site **this** limited?

Comment: How are you adding the image to the Site?

Comment: You have a right box where it says " Image ".